# Angular.js App with routing.. Cannot get jquery ui layout plugin working on 2nd view

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working on a simple angular.js app where I have 2 views: a HOME view and an ALT view. On this ALT view page I am trying to get a simple example of a jQuery UI Layout plug-in working. This layout plugin simply provides a North-South-East-West layout mechanism.

The problem is that while I can get EITHER the routing successful (where both MAIN and ALT pages have non-plugin-based content) OR the jQuery UI Layout plugin working (on main/only page in my angular.js app), I CANNOT SEEM TO ACHIEVE BOTH.

I have this code uploaded to Plunker at: http://plnkr.co/edit/bcqH3jaoS7PZNgC3el4s
I have gone through a lot of angular.js documentation and have perused various articles on Angular.js/jQuery-plugin combinations, these articles seem to be very specific to A particular plugin and so far have not brought me any closer to a solution.

Any advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Jon Kinsting

Comment: what you want exact  ?

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. You were loading the layout via a directive, but since it was in another module (`mydirectives`) you need to include that module in your app.

I simplified that in the example. Now when you browse to `alt` you can see in the source that the JQuery UI is loading (all the sections as getting the expected styling).

For some reason the layout isn't perfect, I had to add this CSS to give it some height. I'll let you fiddle with that to get it how you like it:

```
.ui-layout-container{
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here is the `app.js` http://plnkr.co/edit/peQTwhWFGWvulDZNeeqn?p=preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {templateUrl: 'hello.html',   controller: homeCtrl}).
      when('/alt', {templateUrl: 'alt.html', controller: altCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);

function homeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    console.log("homeCtrl");
}
function altCtrl($scope, $http) {
    console.log('altCtrl');
}



myApp.directive('layout', function() {
    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) { 
          console.log("applying layout");
            elm.layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: checketts, thank you! That was absolutely the right answer. The directives wiring can be tricky. Your solution worked perfectly. Believe me, I'll pass this favor "forward". -- Jon

Comment: Glad it worked. Be sure to mark the answer as 'correct' (Select the Check mark) so it is clear to others that you found the needed answer.